# SQL query to add a column that is currently in a different table

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL. I dabble with it, but get lost easily. Anyhow, I have these two tables that part numbers in them. One of them the part number is the primary key. I guess would have to be the foreign key in the other table. This other table is where the column of information is that I want to query into the first table that has the primary key of part numbers. I can manage to show that part number column easy enough in the first table, but that doesn't do me any good. I need a column called AverageUnitCost, that is directly tied to the cost of each part number.

```
SELECT
    QALog.QALID, QALog.GroupID, QALog.LogDate, QALog.SONumber,
    QALog.PartNumber, QALog.PartNotes, QALog.TravelerQty, QALog.EUser,
    QALog.ITID, QALog.TrackingNumber, QALog.MDR, QALog.ExpirationDate,
    QALog.PONumber, QALog.ReceiptNo, QALog.ReasonID, QALog.RRNo,
    Rejections.NumDiscrp, Rejections.RRID, RejectReason.Reason,
    ProductGroups.GroupName, Disposition.Disposition, CI_ITEM.itemcode
FROM         QALog 
INNER JOIN Rejections 
    ON QALog.QALID = Rejections.QALID 
INNER JOIN RejectReason 
    ON RejectReason.RRID = Rejections.RRID 
INNER JOIN Disposition 
    ON Disposition.DispositionID = Rejections.DispositionID 
INNER JOIN ProductGroups 
    ON ProductGroups.PGID = QALog.GroupID 
INNER JOIN CI_ITEM 
    ON QALog.PartNumber = CI_ITEM.itemcode
WHERE     (QALog.LogDate >= DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE())) 
    AND (QALog.ITID = '3') 
    AND (RejectReason.GroupID = '0') 
    OR
    (QALog.LogDate >= DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE())) 
    AND (QALog.ITID = '3')
    AND (RejectReason.GroupID = '3')
ORDER BY QALog.QALID
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Do you need to use parenthesis for the two statements before and after the `OR`?  It feels like it probably needs to be `(  LogDate < 3 years ago, ItId = 3, GroupId = 0  )  OR (  LogDate < 3 years ago, ItId = 3, GroupId = 3  )  `

Answer (score 1):

Your joins look OK, assuming you have the correct table column relationships. But your `WHERE` condition is wrong, because of the way `AND` and `OR` are combined.

But you don't need such a complex mixture, since you have the same conditions on `LogDate` and `ITID` in both parts of the `OR`. So you can simplify it to:

```
WHERE QALog.LogDate >= DATEADD(year, - 3, GETDATE())
AND QALog.ITID = '3'
AND RejectReason.GroupID IN ('0', '3')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try in this format

```
 SELECT columnname1, columnname2, columnname3,..... FROM Table1 t, Table2,...... t2 WHERE
 t.columnname = t2.columnname ORDER BY ....
```

Not sure what you are trying to do. Without schema, it is kind of hard to help

Comment: I tried, but keeps coming up with error around "AverageUnitCost"

Comment: Why are you suggesting that he switch from ANSI JOIN to old-fashioned cross-product?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean without schema. Does the code give you what you need? The last INNER JOIN CI_ITEM ON QALog.PartNumber = CI_ITEM.itemcode are keys in both tables. By adding CI_ITEM to the select portion I get a new column of the itemcode added to my query results out to the far right. What I really want from the table CI_ITEM is the 'AverageUnitCost' column there. It's in the same table as CI_ITEM.

Comment: I'm not sure how all of those changes to the bottom of the SQL will help me get the 'AverageUnitCost' that is part of a table called CI_Item. Although, they do look a lot cleaner than what I had come up with. For the time being, I would just like to know how to get that column from the other table to show up in my query.

Comment: I've looked at this closer. The Table CI_ITEM has part numbers in the column PartNumber. Not all of those numbers are in my table I'm trying to run the query on, its a shorter list and they are called itemcode. What I need to do is find those itemcodes that match the PartNumber in the other table and give me the corresponding average unit cost in that 'AverageUnitCost' column from that same table the PartNumbers are in. I hope this make sense.